# C# event delegates: changing a parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change a value of one parameter of delegated function.

What is wrong with this? It's nice clean direct approach. How can I fix this to create the proper effect.

Behind the scene:
I want to be able call all events based on a delegate from one place with parameters of image (1st img) by adding own custom parameter to the invoked method which is not certain at the moment until the object which handles the event will be not invoked.

Delegate:
[image]

Approach:

[image]

Error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'param2' of 'aClass.aEventHandler'.

Answers on comments:

1. comment => (2nd img) it's whole code inside and StartCourutine: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html
2. comment => It's true but intent is not to pass Func nor delegate as parameter. I'm trying to find good approach to change one parameter of delegated function the variable func.

Comment: please post the definition of `aMethodWhereIsThisPieceOfCode` and `StartCoroutine`. And post actual code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: `aEventHandler` does not accept a `Func` or `delegate` as a parameter.

Comment: func is of type aEventHandler so it requires three parameters - you pass just one which is a function (parm1, parm2, parm3) => ... The code is completely illogical now. I don't even know what you're trying to achieve leave out the compiler

Comment: @Adassko it's lamba function

Comment: @Jakobbb: cool. But your function requires "string" as first parameter so as you can see it doesn't really fit here

Comment: @Adassko yop you're right ...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
func.Method.GetParameters()
```

Comment: `Delegate::Method::GetParameters()` is using reflection to get the static parameters (as `ParameterInfo` objects), and not the argument values. While you can use this with `Delegate::DynamicInvoke` it will have poor performance compared to other approaches - it also won't help you with intercepting calls either.